# Can not arrange two listview with some other widgets in one layout in android

Tags: android

I have 4 textview and two listview and I want them in one RelativeLayout. But the problem is that first listview takes whole screen and its below views will be hidden.
How can I arrange them correctly so that first listview takes half of screen and another takes the other half ?

This is how it look likes:

[image]

And this is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baseLayerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/baseLayers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baseLayerLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/baseLayerText"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/baseLayerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/baseLayerLine" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlayLayerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/baseLayerList"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/overlayLayers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlayLayerLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/overlayLayerText"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/overlayLayerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/overlayLayerLine"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: cam you send me a mock-up for this , or draw it on paint or gmip please

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi : I've edited my first post

Comment: do you want to put two ListView under Other ?!?!

Comment: yes I want to put them cascading

Comment: your code in all right ,
try to add items to list , and then you will find what you want ,

Comment: add items on Lists and tell me , whats the results :)

Comment: thanks it is ok,
but as I said in my code it's height set to wrap_content. But it will be more beautiful if each of listviews takes half of screen. how tell that?

Comment: Is the item on ListView 1 == ListView 2 ?!?
if it same , your in save mood :D

Comment: no their content is not the same

Comment: so add android:layout_height number , for example :
`android:layout_height="100dp"` for two lists